# How to Backup and Restore SQL server database files?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, desktop-application, database-backups

I am using EF Core in .Net 6 App,
The Project is almost Complete,
But Now I want to code for Backup and Restore?

Here is code for EF, But it is not work for EF Core.
[code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999084/how-do-i-create-database-backups-using-c-wpf-entity-framework-code-first-applic/).

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20639

Comment: There is no code, I seen this page previously, while searching for solution, But Unfortunitly the content was deleted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backing up a database is not within the scope of an ORM.  The code you linked to does not rely on Entity Framework it uses SQL Server Management Object (SMO).  SMO requires .NET Framework 4.0 or .NET Core 2.0 to run.  You can [install the package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo?view=sql-server-ver16) from Nuget.